# Criticise/Recommendations for my code

Tags: java

Before i go any further it would be nice to know if there is any major design flaws in my program so far. Is there anything worth changing before i continue?

Model

```
package model;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MovieDatabase {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public List queryMovies() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        java.sql.Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List results = new ArrayList();

        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "password");           
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM movie";
            rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()) {
                MovieBean bean = new MovieBean();
                bean.setMovieId(rs.getInt(1));
                bean.setTitle(rs.getString(2));
                bean.setYear(rs.getInt(3));
                bean.setRating(rs.getInt(4));
                results.add(bean);
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {

        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Servlet

```
public class Service extends HttpServlet {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Movies!");
        MovieDatabase movies = new MovieDatabase();

        try {
            List results = movies.queryMovies();
            Iterator it = results.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()) {
                MovieBean movie = new MovieBean();
                movie = (MovieBean)it.next();
                out.println(movie.getYear());
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Bean

```
package model;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MovieBean implements java.io.Serializable {

    protected int movieid;
    protected int rating;
    protected int year;
    protected String title;

    public MovieBean() {

    }

    public void setMovieId(int movieidVal) {
        movieid = movieidVal;
    }

    public void setRating(int ratingVal) {
        rating = ratingVal;
    }

    public void setYear(int yearVal) {
        year = yearVal;
    }

    public void setTitle(String titleVal) {
        title = titleVal;
    }

    public int getMovieId() {
        return movieid;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}
```

Comment: SO is not a good choice for a code review.

Comment: Seems like the code is written in 90's. Read about MVC, layered architecture, separation of concerns

Comment: SO may not be for code reviews, but the guy did his part.  I don't mind helping those who try.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "not a real question" solely because absolutely no context was given outside what you could infer from the code itself.  Since the context is being inferred by potentially bad code (hence the code review), it's not a good question, as all good design decisions rely on a good grasp of the context.

Comment: The high quality of the answers has led me to reconsider closing this question.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of suggestions:

- Your MovieDatabase has the Connection creation embedded inside it.  You don't use a Connection pool that way.
- You embed the connection parameters (e.g., driver class, URL, etc.) inside your code.  Best to externalize them.
- You don't clean up any JDBC resources.  This is guaranteed to bring you grief.
- You have empty catch blocks.  This is a heinous error.  Log the stack trace.  You'll have no way of knowing if anything is wrong as coded.
- MovieBean?  Names matter - make it Movie.
- Your default constructor does nothing at all, and it's the only constructor you provide.  Your String reference to title will be null.  I think you should have one constructor that initializes all the fields properly.
- Your Service should not extend Servlet.  I think you should have a POJO interface and an implementation that has nothing to do with HTTP.  You can't use this service (or test it) without the web.
- Another empty catch block - you're asking for trouble.  When will you learn to print the stack trace?
- I wouldn't have a MovieDatabase; I'd go with a MovieDao interface that had CRUD operations, like this:

> ```
> package persistence; 
>
> public interface MovieDao
> {
>     List<Movie> find();
>     Movie find(int id);
>     List<Movie> find(String title);
>     void save(Movie movie);
>     void update(Movie movie);
>     void delete(Movie movie);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Much of the following is style, not necessarily the 'right' way, and certainly not the only way.

1. I'd move the database connection
   to a try block in the servlet's #doGet. I'd pass the
   connection to
   MovieDatabase#queryMovies.  The
   reason is, what happens if in that same request you need
   to do another query using another
   class?  Your connection is in
   MovieDatabase and another class
   would have no access to it.  If you had a situation where both classes could update the database, you'd be unable to roll back the entire transaction. Not good.
2. I'd add a commit statement at the end of the 'success' path in #doGet
3. I'd add after try block containing the database connection an exception block, wherein I'd issue a rollback. So if there's an exception, a rollback would be performed every time.
4. I'd close the database connection in
   #doGet's finally block.  This is most important. **edit - see the pseudocode below for an example**
5. If you don't move the connection into the servlet, then *straight
   away* you should close that
   connection in #queryMovies' finally
   clause.
6. If this were a larger project, I'd use Hibernate and its tools to
   generate DAOs and models.  Hibernate
   would generate for you a class and
   method that would return a
   collection of MovieBeans to you. 
   You wouldn't have to do anything but
   invoke it.  Auto-generated database
   access code is good.
7. I'd add a JSP and put the collection you're building into the request.  Then your jsp could iterate over the collection and format it as appropriate.  This moves the presentation of the information out of the servlet, which is a *coordinator of action*, not a *formatter of data* in the MVC model.

If you implemented the above suggestions, it would probably drop your number of lines of code by 50% or more.  Learning Hibernate can be a **headache**, so it wouldn't necessarily be easier or faster the first time.  The reason it reduces the lines of code (while doing pretty much the same work) is that generated code is pretty much right and coders don't have to worry about it.

I use the following pattern in my servlets all the time. This is pseudocode, not real java.

```
   Connection conn = null;
   try {
      conn.getConnection(...);
      // your implementation here
      conn.commit();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      conn.rollback();
   } finally {
      conn.close();
   }
```

The point is that the database connection can always be passed to workers, work is always committed unless something goes wrong.  If something goes wrong, there's guaranteed to be a rollback.  In either case, the database connection is closed when its all over.

Comment: I disagree - database operations do not belong in servlets.  You can't test them without the servlet engine that way.  Have a service POJO interface and implementation that you can test without the servlet engine; then have a servlet call the service.  It's a small difference, but your service is testable and useful without the web tier that way.

Comment: Ah. You're saying put the pseudocode thing above into a pojo, and let the servlet instanciate the pojo, and invoke the pojo's #doIt method?

Comment: So should i be making a Database class?

Comment: @aLk The critical part of what we're saying is that your database connection code does not belong in any of your application classes.  For now, put the database connection code in the servlet with the catch and finally clauses.  Get it working.  It won't take long. Once it is there and working, the value of duffymo's suggestion will become apparent.

Comment: No, not a Database class.  Think about the objects in your problem.

Comment: @Tony - yes, I would have no objection to your (very good) pseudo-code if it were in  service implementation behind a good interface.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple and straightforward, no big issues. The only thing I would point out is that you're doing a `SELECT *` then refer to the result set by column index. This is not a problem at this stage but if your schema changes (say, a field gets added in the middle) then your code will break. I would explicitly select the column names:

```
SELECT id, title, year, rating FROM movie
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many things wrong (many have already pointed out most of them). Seems like the code is written in 90's. I strongly suggest you read about [layered architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture), [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), [DAO](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) pattern. Then you will answer the question yourself and I will up vote your answer ;-).

Comment: How about soliciting a donation to this site instead?

Comment: I will if SO takes donations. By the way I am not associated with wikipedia at all.

Comment: @Tony Ennis - by all appearances, SO is a commercial concern.  (And I hope they succeed.)